# Inserir corretamente dados na tabela

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, query

Estou com sérios problemas em relação ao `INSERT` do `PDO`, não estou conseguindo adicionar os valores corretamente ao `banco de dados`, como proceder nessa situação?

Imagem do problema:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aguardo ajuda.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btn-send-ticket'])) {
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
    $subject = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'subject');
    $categorys = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'category');
    $prioritys = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'prioritys');
    $message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message');

    if (empty($subject)) {
        $error[] = 'The <strong>subject</strong> field can not be empty';
    } elseif (empty($message)) {
        $error[] = 'The <strong>message</strong> field can not be empty';
    } else {
        try {

            $sqli = "INSERT INTO member_ticket (name, subject, category, priority, message, date, status) VALUES (:name, :subject, :category, :priority, :message, NOW(), 0)";

            $insert = $db->prepare($sqli);
            $insert->bindParam(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insert->bindParam(":subject", $subject, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insert->bindParam(":category", $categorys, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insert->bindParam(":priority", $prioritys, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insert->bindParam(":message", $message, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $insert->execute();

            $success[] = 'Your support request has been successfully opened, will soon be answered thanks.';
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage() . '<br/>' . $e->getLine();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado por comentar, adicionei um update ao tópico. Não sei como explicar corretamente o meu problema, mas tentei veja: Repare que ao passar :name, :subject, etc... para a query, o `PDO` não está tratando a query, está inserindo o que era pra ser tratado.

Comment: Deu pra entender agora :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remova as aspas dos named placedholders, pois não precisa

Mude:

```
VALUES (':name', ':subject', ':category', ':priority', ':message', NOW(), 0)";
```

Por:

```
VALUES (:name, :subject, :category, :priority, :message, NOW(), 0)";
```

Comment: Já fiz desta form, me retorna um aviso: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null
82`

Comment: @GuilhermeGouveiaAlves ai é outro erro em outra parte. O que é que tem na variável $name quando você fez o teste?

Comment: @GuilhermeGouveiaAlves precisa verificar o valor de `$name` pois veio em branco.

Comment: Olha pessoal, adicionei o `código` inteiro no tópico principal para obter melhor o entendimento à vocês.

Comment: @Guilherme acrescente mais `elseif (empty($name))` e pros outros campos que faltam, pra ter certeza que está vindo tudo preenchido.

Comment: Adicionei @Bacco, desta vez enviou, deixei o campo como `disabled` e usei a `class` `hidden` do `Bootstrap` ai funcionou.

Comment: @GuilhermeGouveiaAlves, campo marcado como `disabled` não é enviado, se quer deixar ele não modificavel, use `readonly`